# how to use elements (:hover) to display and keep the table stable to measure it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to cover a website and here is its link https://shopee.vn/demo.vn

At the text "thông báo", when you hover to it, it will show you a table as you can see in this photo

[image: photo when I hover to the text]

My problem is, when I click to :hover and use tool to measure the photo and download the image to copy it, it disappeared.

I think that when I use :hover, it must display the photo ? Or when I click to the link below which belong to the photo, there is some properties like visibility or something like that ?

I want to display the photo to download the image and the text really.

Could you please help me to solve this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

run code below below on browser console or snippets to simulate `mouseover` (mouse hover) then go to `Elements` tab.

```
var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
});
document.querySelectorAll('.stardust-popover__target')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but how about the "Tải ứng dụng" button ? I think that I just only replace the "stardust-popover__target" by "_2QcfeN" ( the class I search by element), but the "Tải ứng dụng" button not show the image like the "thông báo" by the code you gave me ? Could you please give me some ideas about this problem again ?